# jqGrid Lazy load one column

Tags: jqgrid

This is an application which runs asp.net mvc / web api / jquery / jqgrid. 
We bind the data to jqgrid from web api like below.

```
DeptId  Name   Location     Cost
1       Abc       IN      $15500.50
```

The issue is, The 'Cost' column derivation has heavy calculation logic (which is unavoidable). It is resulted performance issue in grid. (loading data takes more time).

Now, I am looking for the solution to load jqgrid partially.

in 1st call, Show DeptId, Name, Location, (leave Cost column empty). 
             - So the user perform any action based on it.

in 2nd call, Bind cost column on each row.

I have changed the web api part.

Questions is, Is this approach fine? Does jqGrid supports this behavior?

Comment: It would be good if you **include JavaScript code, which you use**. You wrote: "The 'Cost' column derivation has heavy calculation logic (which is unavoidable). It is resulted performance issue in grid." It could be that you fill the column in a wrong way. It's important that you write always **which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid** ([free jqGrid](), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS]() or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). It's important to know how many total items are in the grid. An example of JSON/XML data returned from the server (2-3 rows) could be helpful too.

Comment: I am using jqGrid  5.0.1.  And calculation is done in 'Select' query which makes delay in wep api call. In jqgrid I m simply binding the result.

Comment: A little late to the party, but might be enough to load the whole grid on the first query, with the Cost column empty. Then after the ajax call for the Cost values, simply iterate over the values and set the value of each cell of the Cost column accordingly, something like this: for(let i=0; i<costs.length;i++) {$("#my-jqgrid").jqGrid('setCell', i, 'Cost', costs[i]);}